# Numerical error for a graph implementantion

Tags: java

I am working for a project for my university and i am getting always the same error message

> java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   Assignment2.ColumnGen$SubProblem.createModel(ColumnGen.java:283)

The problem is in these lines

```
double M = 0;
for (int i=0; i<all_customers.size(); i++) { 
    for (int j=0; j<all_customers.size(); j++) {
        double val = all_customers.get(i).time_to_node(all_customers.get(j)) + all_customers.get(i).time_at_node();
        if (M<val) M=val;
    }

}
```

When I delete these lines everything works perfectly but obviously I am not getting the best result as long as my algorithm, because i miss this parameter.

I know what is a null pointer exception but i tried everything and still i miss something.

My all other declarations for the things that you see in code are

```
    public Map<Integer, Customer> all_customers = new HashMap<Integer, Customer>();

    public double a() {
        return ready_time;
    }

    public double b() {
        return due_date;
    }

    public Node(int external_id, double x, double y, double t) {
        this.id = all_nodes.size();
        this.id_external = external_id;
        this.xcoord = x;
        this.ycoord = y;
        this.t_at_node = t;
        all_nodes.put(this.id, this);
    }

    public double time_to_node(Node node_to) {
        return Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.xcoord - node_to.xcoord, 2) + Math.pow(this.ycoord - node_to.ycoord, 2)));
    }

    public double time_at_node() {
        return t_at_node;
    }
```

What i do wrong?

Comment: Where do you add data to variable all_customers? You are just instantiating a HashMap and assigning to the variable, but with no data. So when you try to run it in the loop arises the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think your exception comes from all_customers.get(i) , debug your code and make sure all the keys u request are in the map, or you can add a condition to check whether the map contains your key

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that one of your `Map.get()` operations returns a `null`.  Obviously, one of the keys is missing from your map.  You are not showing us how you populate your map, so the problem is not in the code that you are showing us.

Replace the following line of spaghetti code:

```
double val = all_customers.get(i).time_to_node(all_customers.get(j)) + all_customers.get(i).time_at_node();
```

with the following block of code:

```
Customer ci = all_customers.get(i);
assert ci != null : "Not found:" + i;
Customer cj = all_customers.get(j);
assert cj != null : "Not found:" + j;
double val = ci.time_to_node(cj) + ci.time_at_node();
```

and run your program passing the `-enableassertions` argument to the VM. (`-ea` for short.)  This should give you a very good hint as to what is going wrong.